# How to identify ionic tags using Protractor?

Tags: angularjs, protractor, ionic-framework

I have a simple ionic template as below. In Protractor, how do I write the locator to locate the Ionic elements, say the Title and Left and Right buttons. How do I check that the title is 'My Title'? I could not bind by H1, as supposedly there are lots of H1 in my template.

```
<ion-header-bar align-title="left" class="bar-positive">
    <div class="buttons">
        <button class="button" ng-click="doSomething()">Left Button</button>
    </div>
    <h1 class="title">My Title</h1>
    <div class="buttons">
        <button class="button">Right Button</button>
    </div>
</ion-header-bar>
<ion-content>
    Some content!
</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd find the elements [by xpath](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.By.xpath) relying on their tag names, classes and relative positions:

```
var title = element(by.xpath('//h1[@class="title" and following-sibling::div[@class="buttons"] and preceding-sibling::div[@class="buttons"]'));
var leftButton = title.element('preceding-sibling::div[@class="buttons"]/button');
var rightButton = title.element('following-sibling::div[@class="buttons"]/button');
```

Comment: Thanks alecxe. That worked for me. Appreciate you taking the time to respond.

Comment: I wish there was a better way than using xpath.  It's a lot more brittle than being able to add IDs.  I would say this is a negative thing when ionic is the choice to use.  Anyone know if they plan on adding the ability to add IDs at some point?

Comment: @rfodge you don't have to use XPaths to locate ionic elements..the tag names are quite descriptive and there are some good classes and attributes to rely on. Try with CSS selectors. For instance, to locate the buttons: `$$("ion-header-bar .buttons button")`.

Comment: Well, I guess not always - that is def true.  In my scenario, the ionic nav-bar has an active and a cached version which are duplicates.  The only way I found so far was to use xpath to locate the correct one.  And overall, i prefer the use of IDs but with ionic it seems to be tougher for the devs to add them to the ionic built ins.  I prefer over classes since the classes could still be duped over multiple elements.  thanks for clarifying me though.  I should have been more specific.

Comment: @rfodge could you please elaborate that into a separate question providing what HTML you have in your case and asking if there is a better way than using XPaths? Who knows, may be we'll find a workaround. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. In your controller, define

   $scope.someTag = "whatever"
2. Apply your functions in the controller on `$scope.someTag`
3. In your DOM (for example your title), assign:

   title="{{someTag}}"

In this way you keep control of what you are doing!

Comment: Thank you AMG for your reply.
Your answer, though it works, will require a huge re-write of my entire project. :-( I will do it if that's the best practice.

In essence, the view data is replicated in the controller, which seems not appropriate. In the future, I am also hoping to NLS the strings in the view, and then my controller will be bloated.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it working using this for the right button with the text save:

```
var saveButton = element(by.css('.right-buttons')).element(by.cssContainingText('button', 'Save'));
```

My guess is you could do the same for the left button for example a left button that says back in the text:

```
var backButton = element(by.css('.left-buttons')).element(by.cssContainingText('button', 'back'));
```